# Get access_token using Windows Service's or Console App. for Instagram Api

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, instagram, twitter-oauth, instagram-api

My windows service is collect instagram datas from instagram api. I was using client_id but this uses format is removed.

Instagram api is want to access_token but Oauth 2.0 is web-based. or not?

I using .NET and my application type is windows service and web request don't work because this call url: "https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code" is have one more contain redirect. so web response haven't contain my web application link also auto redirect is open..

what should I do?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to get instagram access token
 register ur application in instagram account.
get a client id and client secret.

Step 1: HIT the below url.

**https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code**

step 2: after hitting above url you will be taken to login page. enter the login credentials and take the **code** from address bar.
it will be live for only 20 seconds i guess.

step 3:  The **code** which you got put it in CODE parameter in the below source code, then run the below code in console application n hit breakpoint at response. you will get **access token and userid**.

```
    public void GetDataInstagramToken()
    {
        try
        {
            NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
            parameters.Add("client_id", "CLIENT-ID");
            parameters.Add("client_secret", "CLIENT-Secret");
            parameters.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
            parameters.Add("redirect_uri", "REDIRECT-URI");
            parameters.Add("code", "CODE");

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var result = client.UploadValues("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "POST", parameters);
            var response = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);

            // deserializing nested JSON string to object  
            var jsResult = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
            string accessToken = (string)jsResult["access_token"];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           //exception catch
        }
    }
```